# Show image with JSON

Tags: json, image

I'm trying to learn how to use JSON, but I'm stuck. 
Right now I want to show a image when I click on the image. 
I feel like I'm close but don't know what's wrong.
Also, would this be the correct way to show an image with JSON? ("

html:

```
<nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a id="boek1" href="#">Boek 1</a></li>
                <li><a id="boek2" href="#">Boek 2</a></li>
            </ul>
</nav>
```

script:

```
   $(document).ready( function()
    {
        $('#boek1').click(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax(
            {
                url:        'Booklist.json',
                dataType:   'json',
                success:    function(data)
                {   
                    $('#content').append('<img src="'data.books.cover[0].source'">');
                    console.log(item);
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    alert("Houston, we have a problem");
                }   
            });             
        });
    });
```

JSON:

```
{
    "books": [
        {
            "title": "HTML5 Media, Integrating audio and video with the Web",
            "author": "Shelley Powers",
            "desc": "A detailed introduction to presenting audio and video in HTML5, from markup through scripting. It will explain not just placing content in pages but interaction through Javascript APIs, to build media players that could be used cross-browser.",
            "publishDate": "July 2011",
            "url": "http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920019824/",
            "cover": [
                {
                    "type": "bigCover",
                    "source": "img/cat_005.gif",
                    "alternative": "HTML5 Media"
                },
                {
                    "type": "cover",
                    "source": "img/bkt_005.gif"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "HTML5: Up and Running",
            "author": "Mark Pilgrim",
            "desc": "If you don't know about the new features available in HTML5, now's the time to find out. This book provides practical information about how and why the latest version of this markup language will significantly change the way you develop for the Web. HTML5: Up & Running carefully guides you though the important changes in this version with lots of hands-on examples, including markup, graphics, and screenshots. You'll learn how to use HTML5 markup to add video, offline capabilities, and more -- and youÕll be able to put that functionality to work right away.",
            "publishDate": "August 2010",
            "url": "http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596806033/",
            "cover": [
                {
                    "type": "bigCover",
                    "source": "img/cat_noCover.gif",
                    "alternative": "HTML5 Up and Running"
                },
                {
                    "type": "cover",
                    "source": "img/bkt_noCover.gif"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `data.books[0].cover[0]`

Comment: *would this be the correct way to show an image with JSON?* do you mean javascript? JSON just holds the data, it cant process logic

Comment: perhaps you're looking for a way to use [data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs)?

Comment: try to console first on ajax success data.books[0].cover[0].source and if you want to learn json this link is very helpfull i guess       try to console first on ajax success data.books[0].cover[0].source and if you want to learn json this link is very helpfull i guess http://www.jsonexample.com/